# If I polypile a bunch of elven cloaks (boots, etc), will I get just cloaks (boots, etc)?

Tags: nethack

I'm in need of a cloak of MR, and have amassed a large collection of elven cloaks and boots as well as a couple of robes. Being magical armor, I know that I have a shot at getting magical armor by polypiling. The wiki says that items stay within class-- "potions beget potions, wands beget wands, etc", but doesn't really say "cloaks beget cloaks."  Am I right in thinking that I may well end up with a bunch of non=magical gloves, shields, helms, and armor instead of any cloaks at all?  Does the material cloth, leather metal)have any bearing?

Answer (score 2):

An object's class is its symbol.  Cloaks, gloves, shields, helms, and armor are all displayed in text mode as `[`, so they're all the same class.  As a result, polymorphing a stack of cloaks will produce a mix of shirts, cloaks, armor, gloves, shields, helms, and boots.

The game makes a reasonable effort to match the magical/non-magical status of the result of polymorphing an object.  Because your elven cloaks and boots are considered magical, there will be a decided bias towards producing gloves, cloaks, boots, and helms.